# Android animation: background color change depending on time

Tags: android, animation, background, android-relativelayout

I need some help with animation.

I working on a simple game where users will solve math tasks. Each round have 60 seconds, I use **CountDownTimer** for checking time now. Instead of text representation of remainings time, I want to change background colors. Please check a link for example.

[image: GIF example of animation]

I have now blue **RelativeLayout**, and I want to change color of this layout *(or maybe just moving to the left)* depending on remaining time. When game just started whole layout will be blue, after 30 secs half of layout should be darker, this should be clear from example gif.

Important: users can use "super power" to increase time of round. When user have only 10 sec to end, he can use "super power" and add +30 sec, this should affect on background animations.

Can you help me please how I can create this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, you may be able to achieve this using two separate backgrounds/layouts that overlap each other.

Using your CountDownTimer, you can horizontally translate one of the backgrounds using ObjectAnimator, passing in the time for the translation value. This'll allow the background to either direction based on whether time is increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go...

I have implemented the code to change background color of view from left to right. I did for 10 sec. Later you can increase as per your requirement.

I have created one another view whose width and height will match parent. Also to get the animation for view, I have used "Animation" class in which used "TranslateAnimation" API to translate the view.

Also in activity manifest, to get the first view on priority, I have used "elevation" attribute.

Go through below code.

1. activity_main.xml

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.golevr.changebackgroundcolor.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/constraint">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:elevation="10dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:elevation="0dp"></View>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`

2. MainActivity.java

`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraint);
        view = (View)findViewById(R.id.view);

        view.startAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
        constraintLayout.bringToFront();

    }

    private Animation inFromLeftAnimation() {

        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        inFromRight.setDuration(10000);
        inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromRight;
    }

}
```

`